# WSUS flooded the disk space

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-server-2016

Unfortunatley the silly Me configured to synchronize Windows Server Update Service with all Windows Products. What could possibly go wrong...

Now the disk space is full. I just checked the products of Microsoft I know we use in our company. Now is the question, **how do I get rid of the content downloaded by WSUS I don't need?**

**Should I just delete the WSUS Folder I choose where to save the updates?**

Is there a way to determine how much disk space I need? I have only 150 GB available on the DC.

Comment: Why are you using a DC as a WSUS server and why have you only got 150GB on it anyway - * checks watch * - yep, 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either reinstall WSUS (dropping the database) and delete all updates, or cleaning it up if you don't want to lose your configuration.

To clean it up from this state, you will need to decline all unused updates, delete all drivers and declined updates, and probably more. I would recommend using Adam Marshall's wonderful [Clean-WSUS PowerShell script](http://www.adamj.org/clean-wsus.html). Before you use it, you have to edit it to set the parameters for your server (the instructions are in the script itself), but once done, you can just run it. Note that the first run may take hours to run, so just let it complete by itself.

I would also recommend not synchronising everything; specifically, I would avoid synchronising driver updates, as the vast majority of the updates you have will be those, and they are rarely needed. (If you find that you do need updated drivers, you can download them directly from the Internet and install them.)

You'll find that without the drivers, your system will require less space, down to about 100GB or so. As a point of comparison, my WSUS server uses about 110GB, with a lot of legacy stuff in there (I have a variety of Windows versions to download updates for.)

Comment: Thank you very much Pak! May I buy you a coffee via Paypal for your usefull answer?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I'm fine. I'm just glad to be able to help :-)